# What data type does a URL correspond to in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am going to store URLs inside of my database and I just had a simple question. Do URLs have to be a certain data type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply put the data type should be `VARCHAR`

URLs can contain any number of characters, and can be any length (within reason on the smaller end). A `CHAR` field can only contain the number of characters that is set in the table definition. A VariableCharacter (`VARCHAR`) field can contain a variable number of characters. So since not all URL's are of equal length you need the variability. You could make an argument to use a `TEXT` field if you needed to store really long URLs; however, for most use cases `VARCHAR` will suffice.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason for using `VARCHAR`, is it because that URLs can contain letters and "numbers"?

Comment: @BradFJacobs Thank you Brad, cheers. *(noted)* I keep notes as such on file.

Answer (score 0):

An url has special, numerically and normal chars. 
Therefor you should use the type "VARCHAR" in MySql.